# C++ ifstream getline not working

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to read some values from a config file in c++ and `getline` doesn't seem to be working.

The relevant portion of the code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
// ...
ifstream config( configPath );
  string line;

  Message( DiagVerbose, "CONFIG: %s\n", configPath.c_str());
  bool exists = ( access( configPath.c_str(), F_OK && R_OK ) != -1 );
  Message( DiagVerbose, "Exists?: %s\n", exists ? "true" : "false");

  // This was causing a fail bit to set 
  //config.open( configPath );
  if (config.is_open())
  {
    Message( DiagVerbose, "Config is open%s\n", config.good() ? "good" : "bad" );
    while ( getline( config, line ) )
    {
      Message( DiagVerbose, "Line: %s", line.c_str());
      extension_t extension = parseConfig( line );
      extensions[ extension.name ] = extension.type;
    }
    config.close();
  } else {
    FatalError( "Could not open file %s\n", configPath.c_str());
  }
```

The Message function is just a wrapper for printf and prints the following:

```
CONFIG: ./tool.conf
Exists?: true
Config is open: good
74181 Segmentation Fault: 11
```

But everything in the while loop is skipped. Also the file I'm reading from does actually have data in it.

Why is `getline` not getting the line even though the file exists and is readable?

**UPDATE**

I changed the code above to reflect the changes suggested by @rici however, now I'm facing a Segmentation Fault at the same line before anything in the `while` loop is called.

Comment: Have you checked if the stream is [`good()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)

Comment: @NathanOliver No I didn't and `good()` returned false

Comment: `getline()` will not work if the stream is `!good()`

Comment: OP, `getline` _does_ "work", as specified in the standard. Your first assumption should be that you did something wrong, not that a common tool used by millions of people every day "doesn't work".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit lol I'm really not THAT arrogant, I do understand the error was mine and not a standard C++ library. I meant that it was not working the way I was using it, which is obviously in error :)

Comment: @jryancanty: getline reads a newline character but does not add it to the accumulated string. So your debug call `Message( DiagVerbose, "Line: %s", line.c_str());` doesn't write a newline character, and so the text probably stays in the buffer. Thus there is no guarantee that the segfault happens " before anything in the while loop is called". Try adding a `\n` to the format. And, if you want to get radical, try using a debugger to see what's going on :)

Comment: The segfault actually happens on the next line in my parseConfig method. @rici was right again about the newline :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're opening `config` twice (once in the constructor, and again using an explicit `open`). The second `open` is an error, which causes the failbit to be set (even though the ifstream is still open.) From then on, all I/O operations to the `ifstream` will fail.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Just commented out the second open and it works now...well I'm getting a seg fault now but at least its a different problem :)

Comment: Just noticed that the seg fault is happening before that first print statement in the while loop. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: @jryancanty: Apparently `Message` is broken. You probably did varargs wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You opening same file twice
Remove the
`config.open( configPath );`

before
`if (config.is_open())`